# High current pulses for GSM supply

Tags: batteries, switching, gsm, efficiency, lithium-ion

I'm looking for a switching buck/boost regulator that works from a Li-Ion battery (e.g. rechargable 18650) with high efficiency and capable of providing high current pulses for GSM application.

While I was searching on the internet I came across on this Linear's design note (http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/design-note/dn307f.pdf) and I was wondering if there's a standar topology in switching power supplies for applications like this or I'll have to search for particular ICs like Linear's?

Comment: GSM radios are typically designed to work off a lithium polymer cell *without* a regulator.  An 18650 has a similar voltage range, but is generally weaker where high current is required, so may not be as suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Burst Mode is a control mode patented by Linear Tech. Probably what you are looking for is PFM, Pulse Frequency Modulation and maybe pulse skipping. The idea is to have high efficiency at very low load levels, yet have the ability to quickly  respond to a high load level.